# How to create a simple webpage using Oracle WebCenter Sites

Tags: oracle, webcenter-sites

I am new to WCMS. I need help in creating a brand new website using Oracle WebCenter Sites with more customization.

I have created the templates and pages. How do I use the assets and call the page attribute and its value in the templates?

How do I render the templates?

Answer (score 0):

1. **How do I use the assets and call the page attribute and its value in the templates?**

You have to load the page asset itself first so that you get all the attributes and later you can load each attribute and display their values respectively.

```
<asset:load name="anyName" type='<%=ics.GetVar("c")%>' objectid='<%=ics.GetVar("cid") %>' flushonvoid="true" /> 
<asset:scatter name="nameAssignedOnAssetLoad" prefix="asset" /> 
<ics:getvar name="asset:attribute_name" />
```

Above code snippet loads the Page asset and now you  can load individual attributes using [`asset:load`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/wcs/tag-ref/JSP/asset-load.html) tag (if they are basic asset type attributes) or [`assetset:setasset`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/wcs/tag-ref/JSP/assetset-setasset.html) tag (if they are flex asset type attributes).

If you are more comfortable with Java, you can use [OWCS Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e39356/toc.htm) and follow these steps mentioned in [Developers Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29634/asset_api_tutorial.htm#WBCSD2387)

2. **How do I render the templates?**

To render a template you have to use [`render:calltemplate`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/wcs/tag-ref/JSP/render-calltemplate.html) tag with appropriate attributes. This tag invokes your template, basically the code/logic that you have written within the template.

---

As you're new to OWCS I will suggest you to go through basic examples of read and write as mentioned in [Developers Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29634/asset_api_tutorial.htm#WBCSD2387), they will help you a lot.

Oracle has dedicated [OWCS Community](https://community.oracle.com/community/fusion_middleware/webcenter/webcenter_sites) wherein your queries will be answered must faster!